# TCPIP connection in c# and data sending/receiving in another threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, system.net.sockets

I have a problem with my TCPIP connection Form programm.

I have a code, where I'm trying to send and receive some data from server.
The main problem of my app is how to reconcile some threads:

- myListenThread - to listening data from server
- myReadStreamThread - to read data from server
- System.Threading.Thread - main thread eg. to write data to server
- captureThread - to do another things like capturing images from camera

Part of my code:

```
        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Connect();

            Connected = true;
            this.myListenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
            this.myListenThread.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid host! Try again.");
        }
    }

        private void Listen()
    {
        this.myReadStreamThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadStream));
        this.myReadStreamThread.Start();

        while (Connected)
        {
            if (!myReadClient.Connected)
            {
                Connect();
            }
        }
    }

        private void Connect()
    {
        IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(textboxIP.Text);
        int PORT = Convert.ToInt32(textboxPORT.Text);
        this.myReadClient = new TcpClient();
        this.myReadClient.Connect(IP, PORT);//SOMETIMES HERE'S AN ERROR 
        this.myStream = this.myReadClient.GetStream();

        Properties.Settings.Default.IP = Convert.ToString(IP);
        Properties.Settings.Default.PORT = Convert.ToString(PORT);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void ReadStream()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                this.myReadBuffer = new byte[this.myReadClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                this.myBufferSize = myStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, this.myReadClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

                if (myBufferSize != 0)
                {
                    this.myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer);
                    //myDelegate myDel;
                    //myDel = new myDelegate(Print);
                    //richtextboxRead.Invoke(myDel);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

All is working correct when I'm connecting to server, but when I want to send some string the problem appears because of threads.

I decided to send string, by clicking Button3 and waiting until I receive string "1" from server using while loop:

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.captureThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => this.newGame()));
        this.captureThread.Start();
    }

        private bool newGame()
    {

        string command = "12345abc";

        if (Connected)
        {
            WriteStream(command);
        }

        while (myBufferSize == 0 && myString !="1") { }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

         ...//doing other things
    }

        private void WriteStream(string command)
    {
        Connect();
        this.myWriteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
        this.myStream.Write(this.myWriteBuffer, 0, command.Length);
    }
```

And the problem with connection and data send/receive problem appears, when it should write my string "command" - it doesn't react. MyBufferSize is always 0 and myString is always null. Sometimes an Error about connection appears when I click Button3 (assigned in code). I think it is because in captureThread I can't see any data from another threads. How to solve it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you are using your own threads rather than just using async sockets?

Comment: Is myBufferSize volatile or not? If it's not, the compiler might determine that it'll never change state, so there is no need to check it, or at least it doesn't read it from the memory. This is quite bad way of doing things, better would be to use events or some other way of communicating. And as @Mausimo mentioned, async sockets are a much better way to do things. Threads easily mess things up.

Comment: Can You link me some simple examples about async sockets?

Comment: Asychronous Socket Server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx. Asychronous Socket Client : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Finally, I have to use my own threads, because I'm working with industrial robot (it's controller is server) which have camera to recognize some elements. My general problem is when I'm trying to write string to serv in new thread - it doesn't react. Doing it without new thread - working. The same thing is with data read. The data from read thread can't be senn by new thread...